# PHP pdf creation downloads pdf as corrupt

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a piece of code that creates a correct pdf on the server, but when I try to download it it, it downloads as corrupt:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < $num_tokens ; $i++){

    #$tokens[$i] = pronto_aes_decrypt( $token_crypt[$i] , $prontoKey );
    $tokens[$i] = pronto_aes_decrypt( $token_crypt[$i] , $prontoKey );

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$tokens[$i]);


}
unlink("tokens.pdf");
$pdf->Output('tokens.pdf','F');  

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.pdf"');
```

EDIT:
Here is how the code looks now with correct content-type and correct Output function placement:

```
$pdf = new FPDF( ); 

for($i = 0 ; $i < $num_tokens ; $i++){

    $tokens[$i] = pronto_aes_decrypt( $token_crypt[$i] , $prontoKey );

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$tokens[$i]);

}
unlink("tokens.pdf");

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.pdf"');
$pdf->Output('tokens.pdf','F');
```

The error still persists though.

Comment: Uh, why would you set `Content-Type: text/csv` for a pdf file??

Comment: And is `$pdf->Output(...)` where it sends the PDF data out? You need to send the appropriate headers before that, not after.

Comment: Ensure that nothing in your own code generates any screen output

Comment: Thank you. I did change the content-type to a proper one and I also set the $pdf->Output command after the content header, but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to flush your buffer.

```
  $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!');
        $pdf->Output('I');
        ob_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change content type to `application/pdf` and make sure to send the data before the headers:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.pdf"');
$pdf->Output('tokens.pdf','F');
```

Comment: I did as you said, but I still get "File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported" error. The pdf that is created on the server is correct though.